# JavaScript works on FireFox but not on Chrome or IE

Tags: javascript, html

Following is my code where I create a div with a adrop-down box on my page and I want an onClick event on the elements in the select :

```
$("div.projectTeamTools").html('Organize by Project Teams: <select id="projectTeams"><c:forEach var="projectTeam" items="${userProjectTeams}"><option value="${projectTeam.projectId}" onClick="javascript:onTeamSelect(this.value)">${projectTeam.projectName}</option></c:forEach></select>');

function onTeamSelect(teamId){
        alert(teamId +" Selected");
}
```

The code works fine on Firefox, but not on IE or Chrome.
Can anyone please help!

Comment: Check Chrome Console and see the error if appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$("div.projectTeamTools").html('Organize by Project Teams: <select id="projectTeams"><c:forEach var="projectTeam" items="${userProjectTeams}"><option value="${projectTeam.projectId}" >${projectTeam.projectName}</option></c:forEach></select>');


    $("#projectTeams").change(function () {
        onTeamSelect($(this).val());
    });

function onTeamSelect(teamId){
        alert(teamId +" Selected");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I dont know why it didnt work when I tried writing the onChange event in the div itself. :)

Answer (score 0):

Option element is very poorly supports events such as `onclick`.

This is a known [issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=5284) in WebKit based browsers.

You need to use `onchange` event on `<select>` element instead.

For example:

```
<select id="projectTeams" onchange="onTeamSelect(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
```

Comment: onChange doesn't work in any browser. The div `#projectTeamTools` is a div I have created in the `script` tag of my jsp, which is supposed to call the function `onTeamSelect`.

Answer (score 0):

May be your javascript is disabled in chrome/IE
This can be used to enable javascript in chrome
Go to start->Run and enter following
"C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome" -enable-javascript